# SAML login to firebase with AzureAD with iOS 16.2 is broken

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, ionic-native

I authenticate my users via SAML from AzureAD in firebase in a native ionic iOS application. Because the firebase JS SDK doesn't support the direct login to the native layer, I'm using the ionic-native inAppBrowser to refer the user to a html-page, let them login there and pass the token back to my native app. This worked fine until iOS 16.0 (and 15.x).
With iOS 16.2 the users also can authenticate with AzureAD (fill in email and afterwards password and get redirected), but then it stops with:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().
```

from

```
https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/shared/1.0/content/js/oneDs_641b1cf809bdc17b42ab.js.map
```

where it says:

```
BlobNotFoundThe specified blob does not exist. RequestId:...
```

Does anyone know what's new in iOS 16.2 to either block something here or doesn't load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working in the ios Browser with customAuthDomain, like option 1 from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices?hl=en